# How should I store a list of items from which I will be removing, but never adding?

Tags: vector, data-structures, types, rust

I'm implementing a function where I'll be repeatedly eliminating values from a large list, and passing a copy of this list as a vector into another function each iteration:

```
let mut v = vec![5, 4, 4, 2, 6, 5, 1, 8, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 2, 0, 1];
for i in 0..10 {
    println!("{}", Vector::from(v).iter().sum());
    v.retain(|x| x > i);
}
```

If `v` is very large, this will be slow. Is there a better way? I tried:

```
let mut v = vec![5, 4, 4, 2, 6, 5, 1, 8, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 2, 0, 1];
let mut v = v.into_iter().map(|x| Some(x)).collect();
```

(and then replace the "deleted" values with `None`) but this just seemed unwieldy to convert to and from an ordinary `Vec`.

How should I be storing this list of values?

Comment: Do you care about the order of the elements? If you don't, [`swap_remove`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.swap_remove) might be more efficient. For a solution similar to yours if you don't want to clone your vector to wrap everything in `Option`, you could also have another vector that keeps track of whether values are still live or not.

Comment: "I'm implementing a function where I'll be eliminating successive values from a large list, and passing a copy of this list as a vector into another function each iteration" and you doesn't show an exemple because you like be unclear ? good answer need good question

Comment: Do you really need to copy the vector before passing it to the other function? In your example code, you could improve performance quite a bit by replacing `Vector::from (v).iter().sum()` with `v.iter().sum()`.

Comment: @Jmb The real functions I'm passing it to will mutate the vector.

Comment: @mcarton I do care about the order, but post that as an answer anyway; it might help others.

Answer (score 1):

You can restructure your creation of the copied list to do the removal *before* the copy:

```rust
for i in 0..10 {
    let dup = your_list.iter().filter(|n| n > i).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    use_it(dup);
}
```

If it is important to your use case that you are left with a filtered `Vec`, and cannot change the collection type, then this is probably the most useful means. If the filters are cumulative, you can overwrite the original `Vec` with the filtered `Vec` each iteration to reduce the workload for each future iteration.

```rust
let mut list = your_list;
for i in 0..10 {
    list = list.iter().filter(|n| n > i).collect();
    use_it(list.clone());
}
```

---

The question you asked is *directly* answered by reshaping how you filter and duplicate the vector, but if you are able to change your types, then the answers below may be more worthwhile.

If your `use_it` function does not *require* a `Vec` or slice, then you may be better served by restructuring the consumer to take an iterator of numbers, and passing in `your_list.iter().filter(...)`. This will result in no copying or rearranging in memory, and the consumer function will just skip the invalid values.

If you care more about counting how many times numbers appear in a collection, and do not specifically need a sequential list in memory, you can rearrange your list into a `HashMap`:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
let mut dict: HashMap<i32, usize> = HashMap::new();
for num in your_list {
    *dict.entry(num).or_insert(0) += 1;
}
```

and then you can filter numbers out of the map with constant-time access rather than linear-time in the size of the collection.

Comment: This is a question about performance on big arrays and you `collect` and `clone` everything? And how is your 2nd example different from OP's `retain` example, except for dramatically worst performance?

Comment: @mcarton I don't think the performance is that drastic; if `v` is a `Vec`tor, `Vector::from(v)` should be identical to `v.clone()`.

Comment: calling `filter` *before* `collect` means the second vector will not have to rearrange its contents as items are removed. if the vector is of `Copy` items, the allocation is trivial, but the `retain` call is `O(n*n)`; if the vector is of non-`Copy` items, then no items are cloned and then destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a question about performance, then you will need to benchmark everything so that you can test your assumptions. That being said and unless there's something smart to do inside the function you call (maybe only copying lazily the items you want to mutate), then I think your `retain`+`clone` approach is close to the fastest you can do. Using `Option`s is almost certainly a bad idea: it adds checks everywhere and it kills cache locality.

The only thing that may improve performance is to do the copy and filtering in a single pass:

```
let mut v = vec![5, 4, 4, 2, 6, 5, 1, 8, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 2, 0, 1];
let mut work = v.clone();
for i in 0..10 {
    println!("{}", work.iter().sum::<i32>());
    work.clear();
    v.retain(|&x| if (x > i) { work.push (x); true } else { false });
}
```

[playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ffaeda3d3fec41e0adb7ac529ad2eba8)

Note that this will probably not make any difference if your data fits in the cache. In any case, benchmark, *benchmark*, **benchmark**! Lots of assumptions get proven wrong in the face of compiler optimizations and modern CPU architecture.

Answer (score 0):

If you're removing the elements in order you should consider a [queue](https://docs.rs/queues/1.0.0/queues/). Using `remove()` takes O(1) time to remove an element, because it is essentially a `dequeue` or a `pop`.

Comment: Unfortunately, as in the example, I'm not removing them in any such sort of order.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 sorry, I guess I misunderstood what you meant by 'successive'

Comment: Whilst technically correct (when the succession is temporal), that was poor wording on my part. I'll change it.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 you might also want to include an example of the vector after a few removals and show the contents after each removal so that it is easier to tell exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: The `v.retain` line is fairly clear about that part.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Heres an example of what I mean - If youre adding a number to a list your output after each iteration would be [1]   [1, 2]   [1, 2, 3]   [1, 2, 3, 4]  ...  etc